# I don't know why do I get Pod STATUS = ERROR while deploying a container using KubeEdge

Tags: kubernetes, containers, orchestration

I am trying to deploy one of the examples on the github repo of KubeEdge
This one : https://github.com/kubeedge/examples/tree/master/apache-beam-analysis.
After succesfully creating the cluster (using minikube, btw I am running them on VMs) and joining the edge node, I tried to deploy a container from the example mentioned above but I always get this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2caNn.png)
[When I run describe pod command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBSps.png)

I tried this command at the edge node

> keadm debug diagnose pod <pod_name>
> and I got this in plain text: Here it is in plain text:
> conditions is not true, type: Ready ,message: containers with unready status: [ke-apachebeam-analysis] ,reason: ContainersNotReady
> containerConditions ke-apachebeam-analysis Terminated, message: , reason: Error, RestartCount: 13
> Pod ke-apachebeam-analysis-deployment-85696ff87b-kstn5 is not Ready
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RAq5.png)

Comment: Can you kindly add the *describe* of the Pod to the question?

Comment: Please update the question with the actual error, code in plain text not image.

Comment: @glv I added a screenshot of the describe command output

Comment: @Andromeda done. sorry for putting it in such disorder. it is just a mess

Comment: *kubectl describe pod <pod_name>* better investigate the problem.